# how to read connection string in AzureFunction python

Tags: azure-functions

```
    {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "cost_mgmt_client_id": "XXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "cost_mgmt_client_secret": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
  }
}
```

how to read ? => cost_mgmt_client_secret in python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*python code will be like ==>*

local code will look like this

```
if os.environ.get("CONNECTIONSTRINGS:COST_MGMT_CLIENT_SECRET", None):
    conn_str = os.environ.get("CONNECTIONSTRINGS:COST_MGMT_CLIENT_SECRET")
```

but code for Azure would look like this.

```
if os.environ.get("CUSTOMCONNSTR_COST_MGMT_CLIENT_SECRET ", None):
    conn_str = os.environ.get("CUSTOMCONNSTR_COST_MGMT_CLIENT_SECRET ")
```

so code **will not work** seamlessly.